# Adding a related entity in core data is removing all other relationships?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a core data model where I have a To-Many relationship between two tables, meal and food. A meal can consist of multiple food items. I can create and save a meal that is related to two food items (ice cream and pizza) and they save as expected.

Now if I create another meal instance and relate it to a previously created food item (pizza) when I save the changes the relationship from the first meal is removed! It's almost as if the model thinks there is a one-to-one relationship between meal and food.

This sounds like some kind of configuration issue - does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Could you show your code, please? Seems you add items to the collection in a wrong way, but it is hard to say without seeing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model relationship should actually be many-to-many in this case.  Because it is one-to-many, your food item can can only be related to one meal at a time.  As such, when you set the meal that your food's to-one relationship is referencing, it removes itself from the previous meal's to-many relationship and adds itself to the new meal's to-many relationship.

Comment: That makes sense - I thought it had to be something like that. I was assuming that the relation was only constraining how the entities were generated, not how the database enforced it. Thanks!

Comment: @lehn0058 Nope, CoreData manages the relationship graph for you to some extent.  You only have to set a relationship one direction and it'll do the other way automatically if there's an inverse set in the data model (whether you want it to or not).